# Efficient way of conditional value setting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame of operations in my application:

```
+----------+-------------+
| UserName |  StartEdit  |
+----------+-------------+
| John     | 12-Jul-2015 |
| David    | 16-Aug-2015 |
| Katie    | 20-Aug-2015 |
| Cristin  | 2-Sep-2015  |
| Katie    | 12-Sep-2015 |
| John     | 23-Nov-2015 |
| David    | 2-Jan-2016  |
| David    | 3-Jan-2016  |
| John     | 10-Feb-2016 |
| Steven   | 13-Mar-2016 |
| Steven   | 14-Mar-2016 |
+----------+-------------+
```

I would like to create another column with UserTeam. I know that Katie, Cristin and Steven have always been on the same team:

```
owners_teams = {"Katie":"A", "Cristin":"B", "Steven":"C"}
```

So when I do `df["UserTeam"] = df["UserName"].map(owners_teams)` I get:

```
+----------+-------------+----------+
| UserName |  StartEdit  | UserTeam |
+----------+-------------+----------+
| John     | 12-Jul-2015 | NaN      |
| David    | 16-Aug-2015 | NaN      |
| Katie    | 20-Aug-2015 | A        |
| Cristin  | 2-Sep-2015  | B        |
| Katie    | 12-Sep-2015 | A        |
| John     | 23-Nov-2015 | NaN      |
| David    | 2-Jan-2016  | NaN      |
| David    | 3-Jan-2016  | NaN      |
| John     | 10-Feb-2016 | NaN      |
| Steven   | 13-Mar-2016 | C        |
| Steven   | 14-Mar-2016 | C        |
+----------+-------------+----------+
```

Now, I also know that:

John moved from `A` to `C` on `01-Jan-2016`

David moved from `B` to `C` on `12-Dec-2015`

```
changes = [("John", "01-Jan-2016", "A", "C"), ("David", "12-Dec-2015", "B", "C")]
```

I know how to do it with `apply` and looping over the rows and hardcoding all rules but I don't think it's efficient. How do I do it in a vectorized way for a big number of users?

Expected result:

```
+----------+-------------+----------+
| UserName |  StartEdit  | UserTeam |
+----------+-------------+----------+
| John     | 12-Jul-2015 | A        |
| David    | 16-Aug-2015 | B        |
| Katie    | 20-Aug-2015 | A        |
| Cristin  | 2-Sep-2015  | B        |
| Katie    | 12-Sep-2015 | A        |
| John     | 23-Nov-2015 | A        |
| David    | 2-Jan-2016  | C        |
| David    | 3-Jan-2016  | C        |
| John     | 10-Feb-2016 | C        |
| Steven   | 13-Mar-2016 | C        |
| Steven   | 14-Mar-2016 | C        |
+----------+-------------+----------+
```

Comment: Not sure about the efficiency that you can try with nested calls to `np.where`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `pd.DataFrame.loc` within a `for` loop. In terms of efficiency, you should test and see whether this is performant for your use case.

```
changes = [("John", "01-Jan-2016", "A", "C"), ("David", "12-Dec-2015", "B", "C")]

for name, date, before, after in changes:
    name_mask = df['UserName'] == name
    df.loc[name_mask & (df['StartEdit'] < date), 'UserTeam'] = before
    df.loc[name_mask & (df['StartEdit'] >= date), 'UserTeam'] = after
```

You can also perform the equivalent mapping via `numpy.where`.

Comment: That's definitely the fastest of all I tried. I will stick with that! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

### [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html)

This is the perfect use case for [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) but requires that you keep track of the changes.  Set up another dataframe `teams` that does that tracking.

**Note**

- I used an initial date that was the minimum date found in `df`.
- I set up John and David with initial teams you mentioned as well as initial dates.
- I added another entry to show when John and David changed teams.

---

```
teams = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Katie', 'A', pd.Timestamp('2015-07-12')],
    ['Cristin', 'B', pd.Timestamp('2015-07-12')],
    ['Steven', 'C', pd.Timestamp('2015-07-12')],
    ['John', 'A', pd.Timestamp('2015-07-12')],
    ['David', 'B', pd.Timestamp('2015-07-12')],
    ['David', 'C', pd.Timestamp('2015-12-12')],
    ['John', 'C', pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01')],
], columns=['UserName', 'Team', 'StartEdit'])

teams

  UserName Team  StartEdit
0    Katie    A 2015-07-12
1  Cristin    B 2015-07-12
2   Steven    C 2015-07-12
3     John    A 2015-07-12
4    David    B 2015-07-12
5    David    C 2015-12-12
6     John    C 2016-01-01
```

Per the docs, make sure both dataframes are sorted by the relevant date columns.

```
pd.merge_asof(df, teams, on='StartEdit', by='UserName')

   UserName  StartEdit Team
0      John 2015-07-12    A
1     David 2015-08-16    B
2     Katie 2015-08-20    A
3   Cristin 2015-09-02    B
4     Katie 2015-09-12    A
5      John 2015-11-23    A
6     David 2016-01-02    C
7     David 2016-01-03    C
8      John 2016-02-10    C
9    Steven 2016-03-13    C
10   Steven 2016-03-14    C
```

Comment: I didn't know this method! seems tailored-made for my problem :)

Comment: Yes it does (-: